# CosmosDB bulk insert via sproc - works in DataExplorer, not in Python/Postman?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to use a sproc to bulk insert documents into CosmosDB via the Python API. I'm testing using the sproc suggested here

https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/BulkImport.js

and can easily insert the following inputs:

[{"id":"Hello1"},{"id":"Hello2"}]

using the DataExplorer Execute tool. However, when I try to do the same via Python or Postman, I get the following exception:

Exception = SyntaxError: JSON.parse Error: Invalid character at position:2

I am guessing that the DataExplorer is doing some formatting prior to submitting to CosmosDB, but I'm not sure what it is and how to mimic this in Python/Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you should use json.dumps(docs) to stringify your document array prior to passing it to the sproc.